# Link trees on different genealogy softwares

Tags: gramps

I am making my genealogy on Gramps, I found a cousin who made it on heredis-online.com and an other on geneanet.org.

Is there a good way to link those trees in order to not redo the work ?

Comment: A similar question has been asked and answered as http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/how-do-i-keep-the-different-software-and-online-trees-i-use-in-synch

Comment: Don't consider it as "redoing the work". Think of it as verifying and correcting other people's research! It may seem laborious at the time, but you'll be thankful in the long term that you didn't import possibly incorrect data into your tree wholesale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I second the recommendation offered by [@HarryVervet in comments](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/12748/link-trees-on-different-genealogy-softwares/12749#comment18323_12748):

> Don't consider it as "redoing the work". Think of it as verifying and correcting other people's research! It may seem laborious at the time, but you'll be thankful in the long term that you didn't import possibly incorrect data into your tree wholesale.

I also do not recommend importing the information from your cousins' trees into your own database, as proposed in [a previous answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/12749/1006). (If I want to save someone else's work for study, I either import a downloaded GEDCOM into a separate program and look at it side-by-side with mine, or I open profiles from online trees in separate browser tabs.)

But that's really not the question you asked -- what you want is a way to **cross-reference** the people in your tree with the people in your cousins' databases.

I am not familiar with the three platforms (I've looked at Gramps a little bit, but it is not my main software), but here are two approaches you could try.

**Build your own table of cross-references**

Using a spreadsheet program (I use Libre Office Calc), make a cross-reference  of the people in your Gramps database.  Include any identifiers that you need to identify the people in your program, such as a person ID.  Make two columns for each of your cousin's trees, and enter the equivalent person ID for each tree in the first column, and a link to the profile pages in the second.  (You might be able to do this in one column per tree if you know how to make the person ID the label for the underlying link.)

OR

**Keep the cross-reference information inside Gramps itself**

Does Gramps allow you to store alternate person IDs inside the database, or keep links to the other trees?

---

What I'm understanding from your question is that you want the feature Ancestry offers in its Member Connect feature, where Ancestry alerts you to changes made in the other trees -- only in your case, the trees are hosted on different sites.

Could a Gramplet be constructed that would do this?

This would be an outstanding feature if it could be done, because anyone who uploads their databases to multiple sites could use it to keep their own databases in sync.

**Possible resources:**

For other ideas, I suggest watching out for presentations about how to keep trees in sync across multiple sites, like Janet Hovorka's webinar 
*6 Steps to Choreograph Your Research Across the Internet*, which was presented on 18 February 2015 by the Southern California Genealogical Society, and is available in their webinar library.  Their website is undergoing renovation at the moment, but the recording may be available for purchase -- I'll update the answer if a recording becomes available.

If I remember correctly, DearMYRTLE has also done a similar presentation, and I'll update this answer once I find the link.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect that [Gramps would be able to import GEDCOM](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Import_from_another_genealogy_program#Standard_GEDCOM_as_transfer_tool), so the first thing that I would check is whether [heredis-online.com](http://h1.heredis-online.com/en/domdov/export_gedcom_2011/home) and [geneanet.org](https://en.geneanet.org/help/how-to-export-your-geneanet-family-tree) can export GEDCOM.

If they can, then you should have a pathway forward.

If GEDCOM is insufficient then you could look for whether Gramps has the capability to live-link or sync trees in the other two softwares.

Comment: Yes this is possible but data will be duplicated and then each modification will need an other export/import.

Answer (score 2):

WRT the question of avoiding duplication- something that isn't necessarily possible. For me, the only workable strategy I have seen is to use FamilySearch.org as the master repository of what is "known" or "believed to be true with confidence". There are some excellent genealogists who are related to me and who are quick to offer corrections when I make mistakes with the works-viewable  single family tree model that FamilySearch have. I then use Ancestry.com public trees as the venue to create experiments, researching family lines that may or may not turn out to be part of my family tree.

RootsMagic is, I think, unique amongst genealogy programs in that it can synchronize with FamilySearch and Ancestry (beta version).

Comment: Just noting for clarity that the older TreeSync was shut down at the end of March 2017, and that FTM2017 beta-testers are currently test-driving the new FamilySync service.  Presumably this holds true for RootsMagic as well, although I don't have any information about RootsMagic's participation in the beta test of the new API at Ancestry.  I thought MacKiev had announced that FTM2017 will also have some ability to sync with FamilySearch but until the release we won't know how it compares to RootsMagic.  See https://support.mackiev.com/244426-FamilySync-to-replace-TreeSync-in-FTM-2017